# maven scm plugin - what is the url config-value?

Tags: version-control, plugins, maven, release, maven-scm

Question re. the Maven scm-plugin:
     http://maven.apache.org/scm/plugins/usage.html

Example, in pom.xml:

```
  <scm>
    <connection>scm:svn:http://somerepository.com/svn_repo/trunk</connection>
    <developerConnection>scm:svn:https://somerepository.com/svn_repo/trunk</developerConnection>
    <url>http://somerepository.com/view.cvs</url>
  </scm>
```

What exactly is the `<url>` tag used for?

The other two I found explained here:
     http://maven.apache.org/pom.html

"connection, developerConnection: The two connection elements convey to
how one is to connect to the version control system through Maven. Where
connection requires read access for Maven to be able to find the source
code (for example, an update), developerConnection requires a connection
that will give write access."

But I cant find anywhere what is the purpose of the `<url>` tag?

In particular, does `<url>` have any effect on the deploy-cycle or the

```
mvn release:prepare
mvn release:perform
```

commands?

Thanks,

Answer (score 16, accepted):

From [Maven's xsd](http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd) (scroll down to *Scm* and then *url* close to the end):

> The URL to the project's browsable SCM repository, such as ViewVC or Fisheye.

In other words, if you have setup your project so that the developer can browse the source using a web browser (without checking out the code), the `<url>` tag points to the *browsable* root directory of the project's source code.

The `<url>` tag is not used by `mvn release:prepare` or `mvn release:perform`. It is used by tools such as [Sonar](http://www.sonarsource.org/) so that the source code can be easily accessed from someone that reads the tool's report.

Comment: Thanks matsev! Very nice, I never realized the xsd was so helpful as documentation. Very useful!

Answer (score 1):

For our projects we only set the connection and the developerConnection. I think you can ignore the url.

The url is probably for information purposes. You could add a link to your companys or even projects homepage.